# How to get refcheck output to TeXnicCenter?

Tags: cross-referencing, texniccenter, output, logging, refcheck

I'm using TeXnicCenter. And I'm using the `refcheck` package to display unreferenced labels. This works just fine. Problem is that the log output (that is actually written to the `.log` file) from `refcheck` is not displayed in TeXnicCenter (the regular log info from `pdflatex.exe` is displayed without problems). Is there a way to display it?

Comment: I do not see a way. I think, it would be much better to install a good separate log viewer, see for instance [Log viewer on Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/153/log-viewer-on-windows). I personally know [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/) (open source) and – not mentioned on Superuser – [LogViewer Pro](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/logviewer/) (free only for personal use, starts with a nag screen, if you’re not registered).

Comment: The current version of `refcheck` (available at CTAN) has another format of messages; likely, it is more suitable for TeXnicCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user mov for informing! The newest version of refcheck produces messages that are parsed by TeXnicCenter. So it was basically a problem of refcheck, which is solved now.